401 unauthorized error in requesting to backend
I am requesting to my backend APIs. but I have a problem.
when I request any post API, my response is this error. What is the problem and how can I solve it?
I am using axios for requesting and it's structure is this:
axios.post(url, form_data, {
headers: {
authorization: authorization,
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
}
})
this is error


401 Unauthoriazed means the credentails you sent with the request are not valid.  eg the user is not logged in or  the valid on autorisation undefined / invalid

The backend is configured to check for your credentials, be it user token or API key. You need to supply that in the request.

ok. I think the problem is bigger than this. maybe my all requests. because when I use create-user API, this error happens again. in other words, in sign-up request, I have no token. but there again I see this error...

Can you show your backend code that validated your request token, Try using
authorization: `Bearer ${token}`

axios.post(url, form_data, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  }
});


I am the frontend developer of the project.
I do not have access to the backend codes.  ->
token is something like this:
const authorization="Bearer  yJXVCJ9.eyJVc2VNH0.t8SyBVAQhelwMn_Ys";
is this structure wrong?

I think the problem is bigger than this. maybe my all requests. because when I use create-user API, this error happens again. in other words, in sign-up request, I have no token. but there again I see this error...

can you send me your sample frontend request in the comment, I will edit that

ok. token was expired. thank's for your help...
